# How to set the height for button only for tablet in axml?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

How to set the height for button only for tablet in axml?

```
<Button     android:id="@+id/logout_button"
            android:background="@drawable/bordered_button"
            android:textColor="@color/primary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp" />
```

Comment: You might wanna check this android document out https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: Thank for your comment..please give an answer and I will make it such right  @G.hakim

Comment: Done have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to be using native Xamarin.Android I would suggest the best way of making this work would be checking the native [Android documents](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes) for supporting screen sizes.

When you do you will multiple solutions based on your use case :

- **Using ConstraintLayout**
- **Create alternative layouts** and so on

Feel free to get back to me in case you have queries.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Device.Idiom**

You may have heard of the Xamarin.Forms.Device class that gives you information that helps you customize layout and functionality on a per-platform basis. It gives you info about whether the app is being run on Windows, iOS, or Android, and you’ve probably seen this used in many samples (the most common usage is to add extra padding to the top of pages Only in iOS to avoid the status bar). In this class there is also the Idiom enumeration which tells information about the type of device such as phone, tablet or in the case of UWP, sometimes a desktop app. You can use this class to provide device type specific logic. This is what the code looks like:

```
if (Xamarin.Forms.Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)  
{  
    // apply phone only code  
    mainGrid.Padding = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);  
}  
else if (Xamarin.Forms.Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet)  
{  
    // apply tablet only code  
    mainGrid.Padding = new Thickness(100, 10, 100, 10);  
}
```

This code adds more left and right padding to a Grid named "mainGrid" for tablet devices.

**Use Device.Idiom in XAML**

Now if you’re familiar with XAML a question you’ll probably seek out is how can we set this same logic in XAML? There actually is a way we can set this logic completely in XAML.

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">  
   <Grid.Padding>  
     <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Tablet="100, 10, 100, 10" Phone="10, 10, 10, 10" />  
   </Grid.Padding>  
...  
</Grid>
```

**Use Device.Idiom with Styles**

Using Device.Idiom in XAML or code can sometimes get repetitive and inefficient once you start applying similar changes throughout your app. Styles let you reuse any part of XAML including Device.Idiom. For example, imagine you want to create a "phone style" and a "tablet style" for a page that just sets the padding appropriately for each device size. You can simply define one Style for each and set it on every page. Then when you want to change some aspect of either style you can change it in one place. Styles are a feature of XAML that allow you to encapsulate property settings in one location and reuse them throughout your app. You can create implicit styles, that apply to all controls of a type, or explicit styles that have a unique key and get assigned to specific controls. Styles are scoped to a single page or globally depending on where you define them. I’m not going to go any deeper into explaining how styles work, so check out the Xamarin.Forms documentation for more. Let's see how you can use Styles with Device.Idiom. Following the example I mentioned above with a phone style and a tablet style for all pages, here I've defined my two styles in my app.xaml file with keys (this creates an explicit, global style).

```
<Application.Resources>  
  <ResourceDictionary>  
    <Style x:Key="PhoneGridStyle" TargetType="Grid">  
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10, 10, 10, 10" />  
    </Style>  
    <Style x:Key="TabletGridStyle" TargetType="Grid">  
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="100, 10, 100, 10" />  
    </Style>  
 </ResourceDictionary>  
</Application.Resources>
```

Notice that my styles actually target a Grid and not a Page, but I think you could target a Page object too assuming it has all the properties you need to modify. Then on every page that has a Grid I want to set its Style to my global styles and I can use Device.Idiom to set them accordingly.

```
<Grid>  
   <Grid.Style>  
     <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Style" Tablet="{StaticResource TabletGridStyle}" Phone="{StaticResource PhoneGridStyle}" />  
   </Grid.Style>  
...  
</Grid>
```

Reference: [Building adaptive applications](https://www.grapecity.com/blogs/tips-for-building-adaptive-xamarin-forms-apps)

In this another [post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/styling-for-multiple-device-resolutions/) you find another way to treat the layout of your application in different types of resolutions.

Now, if you can handle this only on Android, I recommend you take a look at this [Google Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support), you can specify different styles for different screen sizes and create separate layout files.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `OnIdiom` XAML element:

```
<Button>
  <Button.Height>
    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Tablet="[tablet height e.g. 30]" />
  </Button.Height>
</Button>
```

`OnIdiom` will allow you to set different values for different idioms. You just need to create a new element for the property you want to set (here, the `Height` property of the `<Button>` element). As the `Height` property is of type `double`, you need to set `x:Double` for `TypeArguments`.